# Parse Java Source Files with Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a bunch of Java source files. I need to write a python script that goes through the source files and identifies all string literals and their location.

The problem is the strings could be in a couple of different forms such as:

1. String literal - "Hello World"
2. Combination of literals - "Hello" + "World"

I have come up with a couple of ideas to accomplish this:

1. Go line by line through the source files looking for " and using that to identify the location of a string
2. Use a regular expression

Do you have any comments on the ways I suggested on doing this or another method which I have not thought about?

In case your wondering, were doing internationalization on our code base. That's why I am trying to automate this process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using re module is the quickest solution.

you can use re.finditer() which returns each matched regex with the content and position

```
>>> for m in re.finditer(r"\w+ly", text):
...     print '%02d-%02d: %s' % (m.start(), m.end(), m.group(0))
```

Comment: Wow! Very cool. With this regular expression `"\"([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\""`, worked amazingly

Comment: why not use r before "" to avoid \\\\

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/), which is a pure-python lex / yacc. It was written by David Beazley... he has some [slides](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/PLYTalk.pdf) that demonstrate the functionality.  This would require a BNF grammar to quantify the syntax you are parsing.  I'm not sure if you want to go that far.

If you don't want to use BNF, [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) is another choice.

Answer (score 2):

See

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/javaclass